# ConTeXt: uniform handling of whitespace in margin and text

Tags: vertical-alignment, margins, context, white-space

Why does whitespace handle differently in the margins than the text body?

```
\setuppapersize[letter]

\setupwhitespace[medium]

\setuplayout
    [backspace=4.375in,
     width=3.625in,
     leftmargin=3.625in,
     rightmargin=0in,
     leftmargindistance=0.25in,
     %
     topspace=0.25in,
     height=10.5in,
     header=0.25in,
     headerdistance=0.25in,
     footer=0.25in,
     footerdistance=0.25in,
    ]

\setupmarginblock
    [location=left,
     width=\leftmarginwidth,
    ]

\define[1]\heading{%
    \dontleavehmode{\bfc\setupinterlinespace\strut#1}%
    \blank[big,samepage]%
}

\showframe

\showallmakeup

\starttext
    \startmarginblock
        \heading{Left 1}
        \samplefile{ward}

        \heading{Left 2}
        \samplefile{knuth}

        \samplefile{weisman}

        \heading{Left 3}
        \startitemize
        \item 1
        \item 2
        \item 3
        \stopitemize
        \samplefile{ward}
    \stopmarginblock

    \heading{Right 1}
    \samplefile{ward}

    \heading{Right 2}
    \samplefile{knuth}

    \samplefile{weisman}

    \heading{Right 3}
    \startitemize
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 3
    \stopitemize
    \samplefile{ward}
\stoptext
```

How do I increase the space above `\heading` without introducing unnecessary whitespace at the top of the page text, below the header? A `\blank` at the start of `\heading` isn't collapsed in the margin, `\vbox to 2ex{}` is only collapsed in the margin and `\vbox to 2ex{\strut}` is never collapsed. What can I do?

How do I keep the space below `\heading` uniform in both the margin and the page text without removing `\setupinterlinespace`? Right now there is extra space in the margin headings keeping both columns out of alignment. It's a slight effect that eventually causes the left column to be about a sentence longer than the right column

*This is an extension of [Implement Friggeri in ConTeXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459809/implement-friggeri-in-context/459868#comment1163538_459868). I'm using margins rather than columns for a reason - mainly to have text flow between pages rather than between columns.*

*Note: I don't want grid typesetting as I intend the lines to become un-aligned as the column contents differ. That and I prefer non-grid standard-TeX typesetting for the main content in the text area.*

Overall I would like a result along the lines of:

```
\setuppapersize[letter]

\setuplayout
    [backspace=0.5in,
     width=7.5in,
     %
     topspace=0.25in,
     height=10.5in,
     header=0.25in,
     headerdistance=0.25in,
     footer=0.25in,
     footerdistance=0.25in,
    ]

\setupwhitespace[medium]

\define[1]\heading{%
    \blank[big,samepage]%
    \dontleavehmode{\bfc\setupinterlinespace\strut#1}%
    \blank[medium,samepage]%
}

\definecolumnset[TwoColumns][n=2]

\showframe


\starttext
    \startcolumnset[TwoColumns]

        \heading{Left 1}
        \samplefile{ward}

        \heading{Left 2}
        \samplefile{knuth}

        \samplefile{weisman}

        \heading{Left 3}
        \startitemize
        \item 1
        \item 2
        \item 3
        \stopitemize
        \samplefile{jojomayer}

    \column

        \heading{Right 1}
        \samplefile{ward}

        \heading{Right 2}
        \samplefile{knuth}

        \samplefile{weisman}

        \heading{Right 3}
        \startitemize
        \item 1
        \item 2
        \item 3
        \stopitemize
        \samplefile{jojomayer}

    \stopcolumnset
\stoptext
```

Comment: If I wrap the margin text into a vbox the space above `\heading` is discarded.  That means TeX is not in vmode after `\startmarginblock` because of the `\begstrut` therein.  If I wrap the body text into a vbox as well, I also get consistent spacing between margin and main text ([code](http://termbin.com/42ra), [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx2Ld.jpg)).  I guess this comes from a difference between vertical mode and internal vertical mode but I don't know any more details.

Comment: I also browsed the implementation of `marginblock` and it is not entirely clear to me what is going on.  The vbox inside the margin is unvboxed and re-vboxed multiple times.  That might mess with interline spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially the same as my answer to [ConTeXt: uniform line height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464242), but with a `\blank[disable,nowhite]` in the beginning.

```
\setuppapersize[letter]

\setupwhitespace[medium]

\setuplayout
    [backspace=4.375in,
     width=3.625in,
     leftmargin=3.625in,
     rightmargin=0in,
     leftmargindistance=0.25in,
     %
     topspace=0.25in,
     height=10.5in,
     header=0.25in,
     headerdistance=0.25in,
     footer=0.25in,
     footerdistance=0.25in,
    ]

\setupmarginblock
    [location=left,
     width=\leftmarginwidth,
    ]

\define[1]\heading{%
    \blank[big,samepage]%
    \dontleavehmode{\bfc\setupinterlinespace\strut#1}%
    \blank[medium,samepage]%
}

\showframe

\showallmakeup

\starttext
    \startmarginblock
      \vbox to \textheight {
        \blank[disable,nowhite]
        % discard leading vertical space
        \heading{Left 1}
        \samplefile{ward}

        \heading{Left 2}
        \samplefile{knuth}

        \samplefile{weisman}

        \heading{Left 3}
        \startitemize
        \item 1
        \item 2
        \item 3
        \stopitemize
        \samplefile{ward}
        % fill up the box
        \strut\par\vfill
      }
    \stopmarginblock

    \heading{Right 1}
    \samplefile{ward}

    \heading{Right 2}
    \samplefile{knuth}

    \samplefile{weisman}

    \heading{Right 3}
    \startitemize
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 3
    \stopitemize
    \samplefile{ward}
\stoptext
```

[image]