# ConTeXt: uniform line height

Tags: context, line-spacing

Returning to this example, I would like to change the "Left 1" `\heading` to a `\subheading` while keeping the two "Left 1", "Right 1" headings vertically lined-up. And assuming [ConTeXt: uniform handling of whitespace in margin and text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463398/context-uniform-handling-of-whitespace-in-margin-and-text) is solved, also keeping the subsequent paragraphs aligned. I've been playing around with vertical `\heading` struts to no avail, but perhaps line correction could also work. Though not clear, the documentation suggests it 'snaps' its argument to the nearest baseline.

```
\setuppapersize[letter]

\setupwhitespace[medium]

\setuplayout
    [backspace=4.375in,
     width=3.625in,
     leftmargin=3.625in,
     rightmargin=0in,
     leftmargindistance=0.25in,
     %
     topspace=0.25in,
     height=10.5in,
     header=0.25in,
     headerdistance=0.25in,
     footer=0.25in,
     footerdistance=0.25in,
    ]

\setupmarginblock
    [location=left,
     width=\leftmarginwidth,
    ]

\define[1]\heading{%
    \dontleavehmode{\bfc\setupinterlinespace\strut#1}%
    \blank[big,samepage]%
}

\define[1]\subheading{%
    \dontleavehmode{\bfa\setupinterlinespace\strut#1}%
    \blank[small,samepage]%
}

\showframe

%\showallmakeup


\starttext
    \startmarginblock
        \heading{Left 1}
        \samplefile{ward}

        \heading{Left 2}
        \samplefile{knuth}

        \samplefile{weisman}

        \heading{Left 3}
        \startitemize
        \item 1
        \item 2
        \item 3
        \stopitemize
        \samplefile{ward}
    \stopmarginblock

    \heading{Right 1}
    \samplefile{ward}

    \heading{Right 2}
    \samplefile{knuth}

    \samplefile{weisman}

    \heading{Right 3}
    \startitemize
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 3
    \stopitemize
    \samplefile{ward}
\stoptext
```

*Edit:*

I was trying to achieve something like this:

[image: columns after]

Or like this:

[image: before-after (non-column)]

In retrospect I have no problem implementing a simpler approach:

```
\define[1]\headinghmode{%
    \bfc\setupinterlinespace\strut#1%
}

\define[1]\subheadinghmode{%
    \bfa\setupinterlinespace\strut#1%
}

\define[1]\heading{%
    \dontleavehmode{\headinghmode{#1}}%
    \blank[big,samepage]%
}

\define[1]\subheading{%
    \dontleavehmode{\subheadinghmode{#1}}%
    \blank[small,samepage]%
}
```

And using it like:

```
\heading{\subheadinghmode{Interlude}}
```

Before I was trying to avoid any reuse of my original (see above) heading definitions. For example I would insert either `\blank[back]` or `\blank[disable]` in all possible locations of the following lines, where `...` represents non-TeX text:

```
\heading{}\subheading{...}
\heading{\subheading{...}
\subheading{\heading{}...}
```

For example:

```
\heading{\blank[back]}\subheading{...}
\heading{}\blank[back]\subheading{...}
\heading{}\subheading{\blank[back]...}
\heading{}\subheading{...\blank[back]}
\heading{}\subheading{...}\blank[back]

\blank[disable]\heading{}\subheading{...}
...
\heading{}\subheading{...\blank[disable]}

\heading{\blank[back]\subheading{...}}
...
\heading{\subheading{...}\blank[disable]}

\subheading{\heading{}\blank[back]...}
...
\subheading{\heading{}...}\blank[disable]
```

Now this (mostly) didn't work, probably because they're stacked vertically outside of h-mode. That's fine because who wants to remember to place that extra `\blank[back]` or `\blank[disable]`? That said I did test them all because accidentally I came across one that works, but only in a margin block (first picture):

```
\setuppapersize[letter]

\setupwhitespace[medium]

\setuplayout
    [backspace=4.375in,
     width=3.625in,
     leftmargin=3.625in,
     rightmargin=0in,
     leftmargindistance=0.25in,
     %
     topspace=0.25in,
     height=10.5in,
     header=0.25in,
     headerdistance=0.25in,
     footer=0.25in,
     footerdistance=0.25in,
    ]

\showframe

\setupmarginblock
    [location=left,
     width=\leftmarginwidth,
    ]

\define[1]\heading{%
    \dontleavehmode{\bfc\setupinterlinespace\strut#1}%
    \blank[big,samepage]%
}

\define[1]\subheading{%
    \dontleavehmode{\bfa\setupinterlinespace\strut#1}%
    \blank[small,samepage]%
}


\starttext
    \startmarginblock
        %\heading{Left 1}
        \heading{\subheading{Left 1}}
        \samplefile{ward}
    \stopmarginblock

    \heading{Right 1}
    \samplefile{ward}
\stoptext
```

That makes no sense... Why would this work, and only in a margin block?

```
\heading{\subheading{...}}
```

Anyway of all possible combinations I tested this is the only other one to work, and in either the main text or the margin:

```
\heading{\subheading{...\blank[back]}}
```

I don't understand, given all the other possible and likely combinations, why only that worked.

I also tried some even more extreme approaches. This one can't work without a second "disable `\blank`" parameter, and I didn't feel like digging through ConTeXt to figure out how to implement optional parameters:

```
\define[1]\heading{%
    ...
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax \else \blank[big,samepage] \fi%
}
```

And this one can't reproduce the vertical position of the heading, but the before/after whitespace should remain unchanged. Something's not working:

```
\heading{...}
\setbox0=\vbox{\heading{...}}
\vrule height 0.7\ht0 depth 0.3\ht0 width 1pt\subheading{...}
```

Though I'm curious how my two exceptions manage to work, the simpler approach is best.

Comment: How about just using grid typesetting?

Comment: @HenriMenke I looked into "It's in the Details" and I couldn't find any information on enabling grid typesetting for select elements. I don't want grid typesetting enabled for the entire document as it would ruin inter-paragraph and itemgroup spacing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the exact same spacing in the margin block as in the main vertical list, then you have to “simulate” a page in the margin.  What do I mean by this?  The content in the margin is typeset in a vbox at natural height.  This means that vertical glue has neither be stretched nor shrunk, whereas the main vertical list is constrained by `\vsize`.  Thus, to simulate the main vertical list in the margin you have to wrap its contents in `\vbox to \textheight {...\strut\par\vfill}`.  The `\strut` ensures that the last line has strut depth, `\par` switches to vertical mode, and `\vfill` fills up the box to the bottom if the content is shorter than `\textheight`.

```
\setuppapersize[letter]

\setupwhitespace[medium]

\setuplayout
  [backspace=4.375in,
    width=3.625in,
    leftmargin=3.625in,
    rightmargin=0in,
    leftmargindistance=0.25in,
    %
    topspace=0.25in,
    height=10.5in,
    header=0.25in,
    headerdistance=0.25in,
    footer=0.25in,
    footerdistance=0.25in,
  ]

\setupmarginblock
  [location=left,
    width=\leftmarginwidth,
  ]

\define[1]\heading{%
  \dontleavehmode{\bfc\setupinterlinespace\strut#1}%
  \blank[big,samepage]%
}

\define[1]\subheading{%
  \dontleavehmode{\bfa\setupinterlinespace\strut#1}%
  \blank[small,samepage]%
}

\showframe

\starttext
\startmarginblock
  \vbox to \textheight {
    \heading{Left 1}
    \samplefile{ward}

    \heading{Left 2}
    \samplefile{knuth}

    \samplefile{weisman}

    \heading{Left 3}
    \startitemize
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 3
    \stopitemize
    \samplefile{ward}
    % fill up the box
    \strut\par\vfill
  }
\stopmarginblock

\heading{Right 1}
\samplefile{ward}

\heading{Right 2}
\samplefile{knuth}

\samplefile{weisman}

\heading{Right 3}
\startitemize
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\stopitemize
\samplefile{ward}

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: How do I replace `\heading{Left 1}` with `\subheading{Left 1}` without changing the vertical whitespace of that specific line?

Comment: @user19087 By using `\subheading{{\bfc\setupinterlinespace\strut}Left 1}`.

Comment: That uses `\blank` from subheading rather than heading - I literally want to make the "Left 1" text the size of a subheading without changing any vertical whitespace, either before or after. That also requires synchronizing with the definition of `\heading`.

Comment: I've tried many combinations of `\heading` and `\subheading` with `\blank[back]` or `\blank[disable]` (these two either introduce much more vertical space before the heading, or discard only the smaller `\blank`) and `\strut` and even `ifx\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax  {}  \else  \blank[small,samepage]  \fi`... but it turns out all along the solution is `\heading{\subheading{Left 1}}`, which makes no sense! Why are the adjacent `\blank`s collapsed? Adjacent `\vskip`s don't behave this way at all - they're added, not collapsed. (this was my main question actually)

Comment: By the way very nice solution, I extended it to: `\definestartstop[marginpage][before={\startmarginblock\vbox to \textheight\bgroup},after={\strut\par\vfill\egroup\stopmarginblock}]`

Comment: @user19087 Sorry to be honest, but I have absolutely no idea what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: So I updated my question, but basically settled on the approach you suggested a few comments above. I think I was trying to be too clever.