# fill all left margin in Friggeri CV with ConTeXt

Tags: margins, context, backgrounds

How to fill all the left margin under `headspace`  in Friggeri example  with let's say lightgray.

The link :
[Implement Friggeri in ConTeXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459809/implement-friggeri-in-context)

I add this to `\setupmarginblock` :

```tex
before={ \startframed[background=color,framecolor=gray, backgroundcolor=gray, width=\dimexpr \leftmarginwidth+\leftedgewidth+\leftedgedistance+\edgedistance\relax,
 height=\dimexpr\textheight+\bottomdistance+\footerdistance\relax]},after={\stopframed }
```

I can use `TikZ` ,but I know it is not recommended to do so for portability.

Thank you in advance

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using tikz inside context. 99.9% of Tikz macros work in context as well. You get a slight speed penalty but that wouldn't matter for a small doc like a CV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could abuse the layer mechanism and include an empty `\framed`. More info on [layout](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layout) and [layers](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layers) pages of ConTeXt Garden.

```
\definelayer[stripes][state=repeat]
\setlayer[stripes]%
    {\framed%
    [width=\dimexpr\backspace-\margindistance\relax,
     height=\paperheight,
     frame=off,
     background=color,
     backgroundcolor=gray]{}}

%Comment/remove this in the original format
%\setupbackgrounds
%  [page]
%  [background=pagebackground]

\setupbackgrounds
  [page]
  [background={stripes,pagebackground}]
```

[image]

Comment: I defined a layer with the same options, but I thought it was wrong. I didn't know you could add both layers. Thanks (for the third time) . I accept your answer.